# Need best approach for list in MVC1

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Example: 
I have employee accounts detail page(view), which contains more than 1 accounts for employee. It contains almost 10 textbox and couple of dropdown box. I need to display list of accounts.

So on top part, i want to give 10 textbox and dropdown and a button named "Add to list" and below that i want to display list of accounts with Edit, delete link. Edit should populate all textbox again with values. User can make change and press "Add to list" again and values should get change. I don't need sorting, filtering......so was thinking if i can do it with normal rendering only or i need any grid widget or something............

Also, my list should only display 3-4 columns only which is partial information from all textbox and dropdown. So i might need to have other information in session or memory. Not sure how can i do this in MVC

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="13%"></th>
        <th width="12%"></th>
        <th width="13%"></th>
        <th width="12%"></th>
        <th width="13%"></th>
        <th width="12%"></th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="comHead"><strong>Food Nutrition Information</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label for="txtDefaultServingSize">Serving Size: *</label></td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtDefaultServingSize", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].ServingSizeWhole), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlDefaultServingSizeFraction", Model.NutritionInfos[0].ServingSizeFraction)%>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%=Html.DropDownList("ddlServings", Model.NutritionInfos[0].ServingUnits, new{ @class = "dropdownlist" } ) %>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <%=Html.ValidationMessage("FoodUnit", "*")%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ><label for="txtCalories">Calories: *</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtCalories", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].Calories.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtCaloriesFromFat">Calories from Fat:</label></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtCaloriesFromFat", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].CaloriesFromFat.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtTotalFat">Total Fat:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtTotalFat", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].TotalFat.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;g
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtSaturatedFat" class="">Saturated Fat:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtSaturatedFat", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].SaturatedFat.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;g
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtTransFat" class="">Trans Fat:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtTransFat", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].TransFat.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;g
        </td>
    </tr>        
    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtCholesterol">Cholesterol:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtCholesterol", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].Cholesterol.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;mg
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtSodium">Sodium:</label></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtSodium", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].Sodium.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;mg
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtTotalCarbohydrate">Total Carbohydrate:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtTotalCarbohydrate", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].TotalCarbohydrates.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;g
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtDietaryFiber" class="">Dietary Fiber:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtDietaryFiber", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].DietaryFibers.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;g
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtSugars" class="">Sugars:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtSugars", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].Sugars.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;g
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtProtein">Protein:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtProtein", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].Protein.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;g
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtVitaminA">Vitamin A:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtVitaminA", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].VitaminA.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;IU
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtVitaminC">Vitamin C:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtVitaminC", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].VitaminC.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;mg
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtCalcium">Calcium:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtCalcium", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].Calcium.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;mg
        </td>
        <td class="style1"><label for="txtIron">Iron:</label></td>
        <td>
            <%=Html.TextBox("txtIron", String.Format("{0:0.000}", Model.NutritionInfos[0].Iron.NutritionValue.EmptyIfZero()), new { @maxlength = "8", @style = "width: 75px; text-align:right", onkeypress = "return utility.ui.blockNonNumbers(this, event, true, false);" })%>&nbsp;&nbsp;mg
        </td>
        <td>
            <%= Html.CheckBox("IsDefaultServing:", Model.NutritionInfos[0].IsDefaultServing) %><span>&nbsp;Default Serving?</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" align="right"><input type="button" value="Add To List" id="btnAddToList"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Serving Size
            Unit
            Calories
            Cal Fat
            Total Fat
            Sat Fat
            Trans Fat
            Choles
            Sodium
            Total Carb
        
        
                
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    " onclick="javascript:Alert('IN Progress');">Edit
                    " onclick="javascript:Alert('IN Progress');">Delete
                
        
    



        
            
                Serving Notes:

Comment: Sounds like you want someone else to do all the work then. Try something, and then come back with a question to ask if you can't get it to work. =D

Comment: Just read the question properly Tejs, i asked for best approach not the solution

Comment: you may want to look in to the Contoso University exercise @ www.asp.net/mvc3 ! there is good tutorial in which the paging is explained :)

Comment: The best approach is to try it yourself. You will learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Displayed as normal list with partial view